# Python Discord Bot - Reaction Role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How would i make a reaction role event.
This is my code i tried with

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    msgID = 05793080854315018
    if payload != None:
        if payload.message_id == msgID:
            if str(payload.emoji) == "✍️":
                await add_roles("cool")
```

What i wanna do is have my bot checking for reactions on a specific message and then give the user a role if they reacted with the right emoji.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are using [discord.py 1.3.3](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/) you can update your code with the following to add a role based on a specific emoji.

You need to add references to the guild in order to reference the role you wish to add. You will also need to compare the emoji to a string representation of `payload.emoji`. It might be worth considering using [emoji.demojize](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/).

Try:

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload=None):
    msgID = <your message id: int>
    guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, name=<your guild name>)
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='cool')
    if payload is not None:
        if payload.message_id == msgID:
            if str(payload.emoji) == "✍️":
                await payload.member.add_roles(role)
```